# How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an Android Application where I'm using Google Map API v2. I need to show the user location on a map with custom markers.

Each marker will show the picture of the user from an URL. The image must be downloaded in asynchronous mode from the server. See the attached screenshot for an example.

How do I add an image and custom information in the marker?

[image]

Comment: very good solution here http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#info-window - already implemented by google guys in maps-utils library

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005956/6667442

Comment: Answer with the result https://stackoverflow.com/a/69883361/8874958

Answer (score 221, accepted):

In the [Google Maps API v2 Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) there is a `MarkerDemoActivity` class in which you can see how a custom Image is set to a GoogleMap.

```
// Uses a custom icon.
mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(SYDNEY)
    .title("Sydney")
    .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

As this just replaces the marker with an image you might want to use a `Canvas` to draw more complex and fancier stuff:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);

// paint defines the text color, stroke width and size
Paint color = new Paint();
color.setTextSize(35);
color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

// modify canvas
canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.user_picture_image), 0,0, color);
canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30, 40, color);

// add marker to Map
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(USER_POSITION)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
    // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
    .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

This draws the Canvas `canvas1` onto the `GoogleMap mMap`. The code should (mostly) speak for itself, there are many tutorials out there how to draw a `Canvas`. You can start by looking at the [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) from the Android Developer page.

Now you also want to download a picture from an URL.

```
URL url = new URL(user_image_url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
conn.setDoInput(true);   
conn.connect();     
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

You **must** download the image from an background thread (you could use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) for that).

After that you can replace the `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.user_picture_image)` with your downloaded image `bmImg`.

Comment: Excellent answer, except for the URL part. You will be downloading that image on the main application thread, which is an exceedingly bad idea. In fact, your code will crash outright on Android 4.0+ because of this. "Might" is too weak of a statement here -- you *must* download the image in a background thread, to avoid a janky UI, let alone the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @lambda k we download the images with background thread , one thing i did not understand sir when we get the latitude , longitude  and url form the web service , then how to convert the url into bitmap in it so fast

Comment: new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                image.setImageBitmap(result);
            };

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return Utils.loadBitmap(url);
            }

        }.execute();

Comment: this works but has performace issues, plus does not cache, handle memory issues, etc.  Look into Google's Volley or Square's Picasso framework to have more efficient downloading.

Comment: its not working for me the canvas is not drawing image on the map when the image is loaded from a url

Comment: @Rishi The magic thing is that URL is fetch and processed by a server side script and returns just only the output from the client side, no processing is done in client side.

Comment: Is is working in Lolipop ? I have implemented similar feature in my app which loads marker image from url which is working fine on all os versions but Lolipop. In Lolipop it does not render the downloaded icon. Does anyone has idea?

Comment: Or alternatively you could implement a class GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter" and then setup a listener "GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()" to customize the marker options. 
http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers

Comment: Not working. The method icon(BitmapDescriptor) in the type MarkerOptions is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap)

Comment: Only "problem" here is that it must first download a image to build the marker bitmap, which means it doesn't show all markers at once, but it shows sequentially as soon as it downloads the next image.

Comment: canvas.drawtext is cutting of the text. Full text is not drawing 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306724/how-to-show-markericon-and-tittle-in-google-map-as-like-google-apps

Comment: @lambda Maybe you know how to solve related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108723/google-maps-custom-markers-overlap-issue ?

Answer (score 104):

The alternative and easier solution that i also use is to create custom marker layout and convert it into a bitmap.

view_custom_marker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_marker_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/marker_mask">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Convert this view into bitmap by using the code below

```
 private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(@DrawableRes int resId) {

        View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_marker, null);
        ImageView markerImageView = (ImageView) customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        markerImageView.setImageResource(resId);
        customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
        customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Add your custom marker in on Map ready callback.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady() called with");
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    addCustomMarker();
}
private void addCustomMarker() {
    Log.d(TAG, "addCustomMarker()");
    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
        return;
    }

    // adding a marker on map with image from  drawable
   mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(mDummyLatLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(R.drawable.avatar))));
}
```

Comment: pls check your answer. What is undefined `view` ?

Comment: @dit Thanks for pointing it out i have updated my answer. Actually its customMarkerView

Comment: can we load image from url using Glide?

Comment: @Prashant Gosai you need to add a callback and when the image is downloaded, then you can get the bitmap from the inflated layout.

Comment: this answer is actually amazing, very creative and led me to solving an annoying problem

Comment: @waleedsarwar86 maybe you can help with related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108723/google-maps-custom-markers-overlap-issue ?

Comment: @waleedsarwar86 Thank you so much for providing such a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 16):

I hope it still not too late to share my solution. Before that, you can follow the tutorial as stated in [Android Developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#introduction). To achieve this, you need to use Cluster Manager with `defaultRenderer`.

1. Create an object that implements `ClusterItem`

   ```
   public class SampleJob implements ClusterItem {

   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;

   //Create constructor, getter and setter here

   @Override
   public LatLng getPosition() {
       return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   }
   ```
2. Create a default renderer class. This is the class that do all the job (inflating custom marker/cluster with your own style). I am using Universal image loader to do the downloading and caching the image.

   ```
   public class JobRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer< SampleJob > {

   private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
   private final IconGenerator clusterIconGenerator;
   private final ImageView imageView;
   private final ImageView clusterImageView;
   private final int markerWidth;
   private final int markerHeight;
   private final String TAG = "ClusterRenderer";
   private DisplayImageOptions options;


   public JobRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<SampleJob> clusterManager) {
       super(context, map, clusterManager);

       // initialize cluster icon generator
       clusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
       View clusterView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.multi_profile, null);
       clusterIconGenerator.setContentView(clusterView);
       clusterImageView = (ImageView) clusterView.findViewById(R.id.image);

       // initialize cluster item icon generator
       iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
       imageView = new ImageView(context.getApplicationContext());
       markerWidth = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image);
       markerHeight = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth, markerHeight));
       int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_padding);
       imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
       iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);

       options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
               .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.circle_icon_logo)
               .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.circle_icon_logo)
               .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.circle_icon_logo)
               .cacheInMemory(false)
               .cacheOnDisk(true)
               .considerExifParams(true)
               .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
               .build();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(SampleJob job, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {


       ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(job.getJobImageURL(), imageView, options);
       Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon(job.getName());
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(job.getName());


   }

   @Override
   protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<SampleJob> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

       Iterator<Job> iterator = cluster.getItems().iterator();
       ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(iterator.next().getJobImageURL(), clusterImageView, options);
       Bitmap icon = clusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(iterator.next().getName());
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
       return cluster.getSize() > 1;
   }
   ```
3. Apply cluster manager in your activity/fragment class.

   ```
   public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

   private ClusterManager<SampleJob> mClusterManager;
   private GoogleMap mMap;
   private ArrayList<SampleJob> jobs = new ArrayList<SampleJob>();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing);

       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   }


   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap;
       mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
       mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<SampleJob>(this, mMap);
       mClusterManager.setRenderer(new JobRenderer(this, mMap, mClusterManager));
       mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
       mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

       //Assume that we already have arraylist of jobs


       for(final SampleJob job: jobs){
           mClusterManager.addItem(job);
       }
       mClusterManager.cluster();
   }
   ```
4. Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Could you list the dependencies for this approach? A lot of the code base isn't accounted for.

Comment: Is the 'Job' class you reference from the 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.1' lib?

Comment: @JonDunn 'Job' in this sample is the custom class.  This is the dependency that I used: compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+. More explanation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#introduction

Answer (score 2):

From lambda answer, I have made something closer to the requirements.

```
boolean imageCreated = false;

Bitmap bmp = null;
Marker currentLocationMarker;
private void doSomeCustomizationForMarker(LatLng currentLocation) {
    if (!imageCreated) {
        imageCreated = true;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, conf);
        Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);

        Paint color = new Paint();
        color.setTextSize(30);
        color.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;

        Bitmap imageBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.messi,opt);
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 320, 320, true);
        canvas1.drawBitmap(resized, 40, 40, color);

        canvas1.drawText("Le Messi", 30, 40, color);

        currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
                .anchor(0.5f, 1));
    } else {
        currentLocationMarker.setPosition(currentLocation);
    }

}
```