# Put a number inside Marker Google Maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, draw

I have done a cluster for markers in google maps. And works fine, but, now I want to put the number of markers that have been clusterized in the marker that has all of them. But I don't know how to do it. It's possible? 
I though in have diferrent icons with the numbers.. but I thing is not good idea, for the many icons that can be needed...

I did some images to show what I want (the result is made by hand)
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812104/1168654

Comment: Ok, I did what you give to me and works fine ;). I used a picture I found, now, I have to adapt to use the default marker .

Thanks for all!!!

Comment: Just one more little question... Where can i found the default marker to use int the "R.drawable.XX"

`canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.user_picture_image), 0,0, color);`

Or the solution is to download the png from google?

Comment: The marker icon resource is not available. You will have to create your own.

Comment: Thanks @MaciejGórski . Now time to do "pins"  ;)

Comment: You may also try [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/), which has clustering built-in.