# Adding custom property to marker (Google Map Android API V2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When using Google Map API V3 I can add custom property in the following way:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: userLocation,
  map: myGoogleMap,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  icon: avatar,
  title: userName,
  customProperty1: bla,
  customProperty2: bla,
  customProperty3: bla,
  ...
```

});

I'm wondering if I can do the same for API V2 Android, the reason I want to do this is that each info window of each marker need to know some information of that marker. And I'm trying to achieve this in `render` function below:

```
private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        int badge = R.drawable.android_face;

        if (marker.customProperty)
        //here I need to know this property to decide which image to use        
                         badge = R.drawable.bla;

        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge))
                    .setImageResource(badge);

}
```

Comment: try in here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You cannot directly extend `Marker`, because it is a final class, but you have some options:

**0)** As of Google Maps Android API v2 version 9.4.0, you can use `Marker::getTag` and `Marker::setTag`. This is most likely the preferred option.

**1)** Create a map to store all additional information:

```
private Map<Marker, MyData> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, MyData>();
```

When creating a marker, add it to this map with your data:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(...);
allMarkersMap.put(marker, myDataObj);
```

Later in your `render` function:

```
MyData myDataObj = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
if (myDataObj.customProp) { ...
```

**2)** Another way would be to use `Marker.snippet` to store all the info as a `String` and later parse it, but that's kinda ugly and unmaintainable solution.

**3)** Switch from plain Google Maps Android API v2 to [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/).

This is very similar to point 1, but you can directly store `MyData` into marker, using

```
marker.setData(myDataObj);
```

and later:

```
MyData myDataObj = (MyData) marker.getData();
```

Comment: thx~ I chose the first method in the end and it works. Any idea why v2 doesn't allow extending? just curious..

Comment: @Arch1tect Design choice based on the decision to use separate process to do real work. Objects you interact with are nothing more than proxies.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Pls. check my question how can i get PropertyID at percular pin click 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784094/get-custom-class-data-information-on-map-v2-popupclick-event-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784094/get-custom-class-data-information-on-map-v2-popupclick-event-in-android)

Comment: @MaciejGórski Hi. I've tried the map approach, when onClick of a marker is called, I want to use the MarkerOptions-object that has been passed to the onClickFunction() to retrieve my custom object from the map. But it always return null. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem with `allMarkersMap` is that it will be re-initialized to empty map whenever the activity is re-created (consider e.g. display rotation). The class `Marker` is not serializable, i.e. the map cannot be stored to a bundle directly.

Comment: I save a json serialized object in the Marker.snippet. Ok it's ugly, but not so unmaintainable. IMHO the best is the third option. :)

Comment: @Evilripper I also like 3rd option, but there is 4th right now. Google Maps API v2 developers added `Marker::getTag` and `Marker::setTag` recently. Very similar to `getData` / `setData` in AME.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Ah nice, thanks for information. In fact some time ago I searched Tag property but I didn't found it. In many languages there is always a way to set an object into an item of a list. :) You should add the 4th in the answer.

Comment: it works!
from version com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0
Marker marker=mMap.addmarker(new MarkerOptions(...));
[...]
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
arg0.getTag();

Answer (score 2):

I used `Marker.setTag(Object o)` and `.getTag()` to pass my custom location obj. to the Marker. Of course the Object can be any kind of object you want.

```
Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position( ... )
                // setTag is not part of MarkerOptions so can't be defined here
              );
m.setTag(location); // Marker.setTag()
```

And accessing that obj. in InfoWindowAdapter is easy:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
   ...
   Object o = marker.getTag();
```