# Google maps - LatLng change my values in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem with lonitude and latitude in google maps.
This is way how I add my markers:

```
Marker newStore = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(store.getLatitude(), store.getLongitude()))
                    .title(store.getName()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(markerResolver("up"))));
```

where `store.getLatitude = 44.04687` and `store.getLongitude = -70.295734`.
When I print marker position after add them this is what I got:
`marker.getPosition().latitude = 44.046873756` and `marker.getPosition().longitude = -70.295734543234`.
Now I want to equal both data to search my store by position, but I can't do that, because store position is different then marker position. Markers position is more precise then sote position. How can I avoid that. I ask that because I have a list of stores and add markers by position. Now I want to get which store I click by position but as you can see position of marker and sotre is different.

Comment: why dont you just put the store name or something in the snippet of the marker when you create it so when its clicked all you have to do is look at the snippet to see what store it is. or just get it from the title where you put it already

Comment: omg, so simple... Thank you so much. I don't know why I skip snippet I choose this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare `Marker`s or any other objects by `LatLng` position, because of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353).

You may instead keep a `Map<Marker, Store>` with all your `Marker`s and `Store`s and retrieve it like this in `onMarkerClick`:

```
Store store = map.get(marker);
```

More on that and other approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17000070/2183804

Answer (score 0):

One option is to leverage the concept of Geohashing to evaluate equality based on proximity between two points. Geohashes sizes (distance) can be configured upon instantiation. So in your example you could construct to Geohashes like so:

```
GeoHash myLocHash = GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(store.getLatitude(), store.getLongitude(), 7);
GeoHash markerLocHash = GeoHash.withCharacterPrecision(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 7);

if (myLocHash.equals(markerLocHash)) {
    // Same location +/- .61 km margin of error
}
```

This is probably overkill for what you need, but can be a really handy option for other applications. Here is a great Java library for Geohashes:

https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java

More reading on Geohashes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash