# Imageview custom marker on google maps V2

Tags: android

i currently know that you can make a custom marker for google maps v2 with:

```
MarkerOptions op = new MarkerOptions();
op.position(point)
    .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
    .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
    .draggable(true);
m = map.addMarker(op); 
markers.add(m);
```

but is there anyway you can take a picture via camera (stored in an image view) and use that image as the marker?

Comment: Kindly go to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview?rq=1)

Comment: This link shows how to use a picture from URL, i want to use a picture taken from camera on phone without sending to a server