# how to load image with Universal ImageLoader without displaying

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to do something like this:
[Android Map api v2 Custom marker with ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)
But I'm stuck on using image loader.

Trying:

```
Bitmap bmImg = imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);
```

LogCat gives me

```
 04-13 14:11:44.953: E/ImageLoader(18542): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Here's is my code. I have an ArrayList camera with all information needed (titrle, position, url, etc).

```
public void drawPicsOnMap()
{                       
    String title = null;
    String place = null;        
    for (int i = 0; i<camera.size(); i++)
    {
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        // paint defines the text color,
        // stroke width, size
        Paint color = new Paint();
        color.setTextSize(35);
        color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        Camera cam = camera.get(i);
        LatLng coord = new LatLng(cam.lat, cam.lon);

        title = Integer.toString(cam.id);
        place = cam.place;                                  

        String url = cam.img;
        Bitmap bmImg = imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);

        //modify canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmImg, 0,0, color);
        canvas.drawText(title, 30, 40, color);

        Marker mark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(coord)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(place)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromBitmap(bmp)));

        markers.put(mark.getId(), url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
imageLoader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                            Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);

                        //write your code here to use loadedImage
                    }

                });
```

Here
onLoadingComplete will be called on UI thread which makes it thread safe

Comment: I made Bitmap bmImg = null; and called imageLoader.loadImage() what you have writed. Inside onLoadingComplete i've written bmImg = loadedImage. Now LogCat tells me java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You are using bmImg before  onLoadingComplete function is called.

Comment: Remember onLoadingComplete is called whenever image download is completed. Since it will take a few time to download the image. So you can't get and use Bitmap before onLoadingComplete is called.

Comment: You were right, I moved addMarker to onLoadingComplete, everything works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any networking on the main thread. [See for description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). UIL usually creates the thread and stuff for you when you call displayImage, but loadImageSync does not. Either create a thread and load it or use an AsynTask.

Comment: There is UIL.loadImage(String uri, ImageLoadingListener listener) that doesn't work on main thread. But I can't get bitmap from there :(

Comment: Do something like this: Create an async task and load the bitmap in doInBackground, pass the bitmap to the onPostExecute method then set the marker with that bitmap.