# Custom Icon on Android Google maps not loading

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Ill try my best to explain.

I have a page on my android app that is a google map that has stores locations on it.

Depending on the type of store, it has a custom icon. The link for the custom icon I retrieved trough MySQL.

The problem I am having is when I open the page instead of showing me the custom icons for the stores it shows me the default icon. But when I go to another page on the app and go back to the maps page it loads all the custom icons. It seems to me that on the first page launch it does not replace the default icon.

Since im new to programming ive added the whole page because I might be missing something. I think that the reason this is happening is due to the method "parseData()"

Thank you,

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMapClickListener,
    OnClickListener, OnDrawingViewListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback{

private View viewInflate;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private Location myLocation;
private HashMap<String, Store> markers;
private ArrayList<Marker> markerList;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private MGSliding frameSliding;
private DrawingView drawingView;
private GMapV2Direction gMapV2;
private ArrayList<Store> storeList;
private ArrayList<Store> selectedStoreList;
private Store selectedStore;
Queries q;
MGAsyncTask task;

public MapFragment() { }

@Override
public void onDestroyView()  {
    super.onDestroyView();
    try {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            FragmentManager fManager = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fManager.beginTransaction()
                    .remove(fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).commit();
            googleMap = null;
        }

        if (viewInflate != null) {
            ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewInflate.getParent();
            if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }

    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map2, null);
    return viewInflate;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageOnFail(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    final MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    q = main.getQueries();

    frameSliding = (MGSliding) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.frameSliding);
    Animation animationIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(),
            R.anim.slide_up2);

//      int i = android.R.anim.slide_out_right;
    Animation animationOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(),
            R.anim.slide_down2);

    frameSliding.setInAnimation(animationIn);
    frameSliding.setOutAnimation(animationOut);
    frameSliding.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ImageView imgViewDraw = (ImageView)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewDraw);
    imgViewDraw.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imgViewRefresh = (ImageView)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewRefresh);
    imgViewRefresh.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imgViewRoute = (ImageView)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewRoute);
    imgViewRoute.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imgViewLocation = (ImageView)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLocation);
    imgViewLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imgViewNearby = (ImageView)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewNearby);
    imgViewNearby.setOnClickListener(this);

    main.showSwipeProgress();

    FragmentManager fManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            ((SupportMapFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));

    if(supportMapFragment == null) {
        fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));
    }

    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);

    markers = new HashMap<String, Store>();
    markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();

}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    FragmentManager fManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            ((SupportMapFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));

    if(supportMapFragment == null) {
        fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap));
    }

    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myLocation = location;
        }
    });
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            if(frameSliding.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                frameSliding.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    gMapV2 = new GMapV2Direction();
    drawingView = (DrawingView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    drawingView.setBrushSize(5);
    drawingView.setPolygonFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_black_color_opacity));
    drawingView.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_black_color));
    drawingView.setPolylineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_black_color));
    drawingView.setGoogleMap(googleMap);
    drawingView.setOnDrawingViewListener(this);

    if(MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(getActivity())) {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getData();
            }
        }, Config.DELAY_SHOW_ANIMATION + 500);
    }
    else {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getData();
            }
        }, Config.DELAY_SHOW_ANIMATION + 500);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Store store = markers.get(marker.getId());
    selectedStore = store;
    if(myLocation != null) {
        Location loc = new Location("marker");
        loc.setLatitude(marker.getPosition().latitude);
        loc.setLongitude(marker.getPosition().longitude);

        double meters = myLocation.distanceTo(loc);
        double miles = meters * 0.000621371f;
        String str = String.format("%.1f %s",
                miles,
                MGUtilities.getStringFromResource(getActivity(), R.string.mi));

        TextView tvDistance = (TextView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
        tvDistance.setText(str);
    }

    final MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    q = main.getQueries();
    frameSliding.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ImageView imgViewThumb = (ImageView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imageViewThumb);
    Photo p = q.getPhotoByStoreId(store.getStore_id());
    if(p != null) {
        MainActivity.getImageLoader().displayImage(p.getPhoto_url(), imgViewThumb, options);
    }
    else {
        imgViewThumb.setImageResource(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER);
    }

    imgViewThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("store", store);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    TextView tvSubtitle = (TextView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtitle);

    tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(store.getStore_name()));
    tvSubtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(store.getIdade()));

    ToggleButton toggleButtonFave = (ToggleButton) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonFave);
    toggleButtonFave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            checkFave(v, store);
        }
    });

    Favorite fave = q.getFavoriteByStoreId(store.getStore_id());
    toggleButtonFave.setChecked(true);
    if(fave == null)
        toggleButtonFave.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    frameSliding.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void checkFave(View view, Store store) {
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)this.getActivity();
    Queries q = mainActivity.getQueries();
    Favorite fave = q.getFavoriteByStoreId(store.getStore_id());
    if(fave != null) {
        q.deleteFavorite(store.getStore_id());
        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
    }
    else {
        fave = new Favorite();
        fave.setStore_id(store.getStore_id());
        q.insertFavorite(fave);
        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgViewDraw:
            drawingView.enableDrawing(true);
            drawingView.startDrawingPolygon(true);
            break;
        case R.id.imgViewRefresh:
            addStoreMarkers();
            break;
        case R.id.imgViewRoute:
            getDirections();
            break;
        case R.id.imgViewLocation:
            getMyLocation();
            break;
        case R.id.imgViewNearby:
            getNearby();
            break;
    }
}

ArrayList<Marker> markers1;

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Override
public void onUserDidFinishDrawPolygon(PolygonOptions polygonOptions) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    googleMap.clear();
    googleMap.addPolygon( polygonOptions );
    markers1 = getMarkersInsidePoly(polygonOptions, null, markerList);
    markers = new HashMap<String, Store>();
    markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    selectedStoreList = new ArrayList<Store>();
    markerList.clear();
    markers.clear();
    for(Marker mark1 : markers1) {
        for(Store entry : storeList) {
            if(mark1.getTitle().toLowerCase().compareTo(entry.getStore_name().toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                Marker mark = createMarker(entry);
                markerList.add(mark);
                markers.put(mark.getId(), entry);
                selectedStoreList.add(entry);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    drawingView.enableDrawing(false);
    drawingView.resetPolygon();
    drawingView.startNew();
}

@Override
public void onUserDidFinishDrawPolyline(PolylineOptions polylineOptions) { }

public ArrayList<Marker> getMarkersInsidePoly(PolygonOptions polygonOptions,
                                              PolylineOptions polylineOptions,  ArrayList<Marker> markers) {

    ArrayList<Marker> markersFound = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    for(Marker mark : markers) {
        Boolean isFound = polygonOptions != null ?
                drawingView.latLongContainsInPolygon(mark.getPosition(), polygonOptions) :
                drawingView.latLongContainsInPolyline(mark.getPosition(), polylineOptions);

        if(isFound) {
            markersFound.add(mark);
        }
    }
    return markersFound;
}

public void addStoreMarkers() {
    if(googleMap != null)
        googleMap.clear();

    try {
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
        Queries q = main.getQueries();
        storeList = q.getStores();
        markerList.clear();
        markers.clear();
        for(Store entry: storeList) {
            if(entry.getLat() == 0 || entry.getLon() == 0)
                continue;

            Marker mark = createMarker(entry);
            markerList.add(mark);
            markers.put(mark.getId(), entry);
        }
        showBoundedMap();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getDirections() {
    if(selectedStore == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.select_one_store, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    MGAsyncTask asyncTask = new MGAsyncTask(getActivity());
    asyncTask.setMGAsyncTaskListener(new OnMGAsyncTaskListener() {

        private ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> allDirections;

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) { }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            allDirections = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(ArrayList<LatLng> directions : allDirections) {
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
                for(LatLng latLng : directions) {
                    rectLine.add(latLng);
                }
                googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
            }

            if(allDirections.size() <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.cannot_determine_direction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseData();
            if(myLocation != null && selectedStore != null) {
                LatLng marker1 = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
                LatLng marker2 = new LatLng(selectedStore.getLat(), selectedStore.getLon());

                Document doc = gMapV2.getDocument1(
                        marker1, marker2, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = gMapV2.getDirection(doc);

                allDirections.add(directionPoint);
            }
        }
    });
    asyncTask.startAsyncTask();
}

private void getMyLocation() {
    if(myLocation == null) {
        MGUtilities.showAlertView(
                getActivity(),
                R.string.location_error,
                R.string.cannot_determine_location);

        return;
    }

    addStoreMarkers();
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Config.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    googleMap.moveCamera(zoom);
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
            new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));

    googleMap.animateCamera(center);
}

private void getNearby() {
    if(googleMap != null)
        googleMap.clear();

    if(myLocation == null) {
        MGUtilities.showAlertView(
                getActivity(),
                R.string.route_error,
                R.string.route_error_details);
        return;
    }

    try {
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
        Queries q = main.getQueries();
        storeList = q.getStores();
        markerList.clear();
        markers.clear();
        for(Store entry: storeList) {
            Location destination = new Location("Origin");
            destination.setLatitude(entry.getLat());
            destination.setLongitude(entry.getLon());
            double distance = myLocation.distanceTo(destination);

            if(distance <= Config.MAX_RADIUS_NEARBY_IN_METERS) {
                Marker mark = createMarker(entry);
                markerList.add(mark);
                markers.put(mark.getId(), entry);
            }
        }

        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Config.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);
        googleMap.moveCamera(zoom);
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
                new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));

        googleMap.animateCamera(center);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showBoundedMap() {
    if(markerList == null && markerList.size() == 0 ) {
        MGUtilities.showNotifier(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.offsetY, R.string.failed_data);
        return;
    }

    if(markerList.size() > 0) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (int i = 0; i < markerList.size(); i++) {
            Marker marker = markerList.get(i);
            bld.include(marker.getPosition());
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = bld.build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                        this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
                        this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels,
                        70));
    }
    else {
        MGUtilities.showNotifier(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.offsetY, R.string.no_results_found);
        Location loc = MainActivity.location;
        if(loc != null) {
            googleMap.moveCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 70));
        }
    }
}

private Marker createMarker(Store store) {
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    Spanned name = Html.fromHtml(store.getStore_name());
    name = Html.fromHtml(name.toString());
    Spanned storeAddress = Html.fromHtml("R$ " + store.getHora() + " /hr");
    storeAddress = Html.fromHtml(storeAddress.toString());
    markerOptions.title( name.toString() );

    String address = storeAddress.toString();
    if(address.length() > 50)
        address = storeAddress.toString().substring(0,  50) + "...";

    markerOptions.snippet(address);
    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(store.getLat(), store.getLon()));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin_orange));

    Marker mark = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mark.setInfoWindowAnchor(Config.MAP_INFO_WINDOW_X_OFFSET, 0);

    Category cat = q.getCategoryByCategoryId(store.getCategory_id());

    if(cat != null && cat.getCategory_icon() != null) {
        MGHSquareImageView imgView = new MGHSquareImageView(getActivity());
        imgView.setMarker(mark);
        imgView.setMarkerOptions(markerOptions);
        imgView.setTag(store);
        MainActivity.getImageLoader().displayImage(
                cat.getCategory_icon(), imgView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                                FailReason failReason) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, final View view, final Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(loadedImage != null) {
                            MGHSquareImageView v = (MGHSquareImageView)view;
                            Marker m = (Marker)v.getMarker();
                            m.remove();

                            MarkerOptions opt = (MarkerOptions)v.getMarkerOptions();
                            opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadedImage));
                            Marker mark = googleMap.addMarker(opt);
                            Store s = (Store) v.getTag();

                            if(markers.containsKey(m.getId())) {
                                markerList.remove(m);
                                markerList.add(mark);
                                markers.remove(m);
                                markers.put(mark.getId(), s);
                            }
                            else {
                                markers.put(mark.getId(), s);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.e("LOADED IMAGE", "IS NULL");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) { }
                });
    }

    return mark;
}

public void getData() {
    final MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    main.showSwipeProgress();

    task = new MGAsyncTask(getActivity());
    task.setMGAsyncTaskListener(new OnMGAsyncTaskListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) { }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            asyncTask.dialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            main.hideSwipeProgress();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.imgViewRefresh4).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 0);
            addStoreMarkers();
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Config.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);
            googleMap.moveCamera(zoom);
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(
                    new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));

            googleMap.animateCamera(center);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseData();

        }
    });
    task.execute();
}

public void parseData() {
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
    Queries q = main.getQueries();

    DataParser parser = new DataParser();
    Data data = parser.getData(Config.GET_STORES_JSON_URL);
    if(data != null) {
        if(data.getStores() != null && data.getStores().size() > 0) {
            q.deleteTable("stores");
            for(Store store : data.getStores()) {
                q.insertStore(store);
            }
        }
        if(data.getCategories() != null && data.getCategories().size() > 0) {
            q.deleteTable("categories");
            for(Category cat : data.getCategories()) {
                q.insertCategory(cat);
            }
        }
        if(data.getPhotos() != null && data.getPhotos().size() > 0) {
            q.deleteTable("photos");
            for(Photo photo : data.getPhotos()) {
                q.insertPhoto(photo);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hey please can you share screen shot how kind of custom view you need??

Comment: Are you want this type of View Read this link question and my ans also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560091/add-an-image-for-android-marker-info-window/38560239#38560239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image) on how to customize the marker image.

You can replace the default marker image with a custom marker image, often called an icon. Custom icons are always set as a `BitmapDescriptor`, and defined using one of the methods in the [`BitmapDescriptorFactory` class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory).

Here is a sample code on how to create a marker with a custom icon.

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(MELBOURNE)
.title("Melbourne")
.snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

> [NOTE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#june_27_2016):
>   `getMap()` is already deprecated, so use `getMapAsync()` in your code.

For more information, check these related SO question.

- [How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2)
- [create custom marker icons on runtime using android xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058416/create-custom-marker-icons-on-runtime-using-android-xml?noredirect=1&lq=1)