# Moving marker regularly on Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a application in android on Google map using Google API V2. Map show my current location very nicely when click on marker. Now i want to move marker (want to be a car image in place of marker). when ever i move from one location(source/current location) to another(destination). This car image should be move regularly on Map.e.g in below image. And on my destination when i click the car image it show me destination address. I Google it too much for that i found different stackoverflow, tutorails but they didn't meet my requirements exactly. May be i am goggling in wrong direction.

Please help me in form of tutorials, stacksoverflow or any other and also with some detail that how can i complete this task in my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview) tells you how to add an image of a car to your marker, using an imageView. Also, you probably want to use an onLocationChanged method within a LocationListener like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             latitude = location.getLatitude();
             longitude = location.getLongitude();
             latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
```

and add a function within the same onLocationChanged method to set the location of the marker using latLng or latitude and longitude.

[This page](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2014/04/20/android-working-with-google-maps-v2-and-custom-markers) also has information and an example about custom markers, mostly found at the bottom, just above the simulator image.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the image of a car as a marker for your current location.
2. Request location updates using a `LocationListener`.
3. Get location updates in the `onLocationChanged` method.
4. Animate the camera to the the new location.

Comment: Could you give a snippet on number 4 please?