# how to draw a line to cover an area of a map [android google map V2]

Tags: android, google-maps, location, polygon, google-maps-api-2

I want to do something like this:

I want to mark a particular area on the map like below image. and i want to show a message , if my current location is inside that area. im new to google map. i just followed some google map tutorials. i heard about something call polygons in google maps..but i don't have much idea of it.. can someone please tell me an approach to overcome with my problem.i am glad if someone can give me code samples,links with the answer.

[image]
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use  this code and use the link below to similar kind of  question asked. I use that answer and it works for me

```
mapClmbo = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(colombo)
    .title("Colombo")
    .snippet("Population: 70,000")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

[How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)

Comment: no.. i was not looking about how to add a marker. can you see there is a blue line covered a particular area in the map? that is what i wanted..thank you for the answer but can you tell me about how to draw a line to cover an area ?