# Make a android app maps marker

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-applicationinfo

Hello I want to know how it could make an android application of markers (warnings ) in a map, for example radar warnings, notices of free parkings... where people can get and put that information in a same map. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you're going to need to do is familiarise yourself with the GoogleMaps Android API v2:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

Have a look at the [samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/code-samples) which should help you to get up and running.

It also sounds as though you're going to need to add custom markers to your map, check out the following stackoverflow question - [How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview) for something to get you started.