# Drawing custom shapes

Tags: android

i want to show a custom marker in google maps and marker's color is subjected to change dynamically when some specific events happen.So i was wondering which is the best way to draw shape like a map marker [image]

Comment: Try this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker).

Comment: Don't overthink, use .png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a custom view that will draw shape like default marker.
Here is the code :

```
public class CustomView extends View {
private Paint paint;
private RectF oval;
private Path fillPath;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    oval.bottom = getHeight();
    oval.left = 0;
    oval.right = getWidth();
    oval.top = 0;
    // canvas.drawRect(oval, paint);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, -180, true, paint);

    fillPath.moveTo(0, getHeight() / 2); // Your origin point
    fillPath.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight() / 2); // First point
    // Repeat above line for all points on your line graph
    fillPath.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, getHeight()); // Final point
    fillPath.lineTo(0, getHeight() / 2); // Same origin point
    canvas.drawPath(fillPath, paint);

}

private void init() {
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setLayoutParams(params);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    oval = new RectF();
    fillPath = new Path();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    Log.e("H" + width, "W" + height);

}

  }
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

**@sijeesh:** Yes.You can set **Custom Marker** (Image Should be Small) .

Markers indicate single locations on the map. **You can customize your markers by changing the default color, or replacing the marker icon with a custom image**.

**First import the following class:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Now you can set Custom marker this way

```
MarkerOptions custommarker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_custom_icon));
```

For more info Please Have a look [Android Custom marker with ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)

### My Advise

Please follow *Official documentations*.I hope it will helps you .

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Comment: hi, i know that we can draw custom marker, but my question is how to draw that particular shape at runtime using shape drawable

Comment: @sijeesh : Try to create a custom view, in onDraw() method you could draw any shape as per your requirement. Then, create the bitmap of the custom view and pass the bitmap to the MarkerOptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change color of marker, you'd better make marker icon as a simple image and just change its tinting color when required.

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_brush_black_24dp);
        Bitmap colored = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(colored);
        canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(colored));
```