# Android Google Map Custom marker with ImageView to be shown on marker icon

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know this is very similar to one of the previous question asked by someone which is on [The same problem i am facing now(This is not the solution i am waiting for)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview).

As that question got closeed by StackOverflow team but i realy need the answer that how to show the image view on the custom marker.

Though i dont have that much reputation to post a picture over here so i am posting the link please see it..

My custom marker which is static look there is a round shape on the marker,on that i want to show image view which is coming from an url

[image]

Here is a sample of an image view which i want to show on the round shape of custom marker. this is one of from many image comes from web service which i want to show on custom marker

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why it's not the solution you are waiting for. It's correct solution and the way you should do it.

Comment: i know but i followed all the step but still cant get the url section.

Comment: So maybe post your current solution, say what is working, what is not and where exactly is your problem.

Comment: Please atleast see my question follow my links which i provided

Comment: Nobody will do all the work for you, there is very clear way described how to do it. If you have problems implementing your solution try to post some code and specify where excatly your problem is.

Comment: thank you sir for your precious time let me try once more with this code..if again i face any problem then let you know about it.