# How to Set background image of a custom google map marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, background-image, google-maps-markers

[image: Here is the Custom Map Marker icon and on the above **white round** part i have to set image][image: It is one of the image coming for Webservice which i need to set background of the marker i mean to set on the **white round** part]

**I have a custom image for Google Marker but another image i have to set on its background.**

> Is it possible to set background image of a map Marker?

Comment: you mean custom marker..???

Comment: Yes On Custom marker i have to set an background image on the above portion

Comment: see my and Abx 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ,You can

Try this so question [How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)

Also read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of @Abx

You can add custom marker like that,

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_me))
            .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
```

Thanks to @Abx

Comment: In that answer mMap.addMarker is written twice ?

Comment: No i need to set an image on the background of Custom Marker Nils

Comment: can you post any example you are looking for..??

Comment: See Nils I have edited my question and there are two images i have to set the small image one on the white round part of the marker Icon image.