# How to set a background image to google maps - android

Tags: android, google-maps

[How to Set background image of a custom google map marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819702/how-to-set-background-image-of-a-custom-google-map-marker)
this question is not about the marker mentioned in the above question link

its about the background of a land

As we set background image to google map makers 
is there anyway to set a background image to highlight a special Continent using android?

any help or a reference

Comment: will you try anything ?

Comment: Have you tried to geofence that region and you could draw an image or set background to a geofenced area in map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set background image of a custom google map marker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819702/how-to-set-background-image-of-a-custom-google-map-marker)

Comment: Harshad - it is not about a marker.

Comment: is there any way to add a background image to a area .. as an example if we  separate Australia is there any way to add a background image  rather than adding a polygon or a color

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate a new `GroundOverlayOptions` object.

Specify the image as a `BitmapDescriptor`.
Set the position of the image using one of the available methods:

```
position(LatLng location, float width, float height)
position(LatLng location, float width)
positionFromBounds(LatLngBounds bounds)
```

Set any optional properties, such as transparency, as desired.

Call `GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay()` to add the image to the map.

Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) and [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions)

Answer (score 2):

You need to draw a polygon by selecting some points on map.

Example code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapClickListener, 
    OnMapLongClickListener, 
    OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Location myLocation;
    boolean markerClicked;
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
    Polygon polygon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) manager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) 
    {
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point).title(point.toString()));

        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) 
    {

        if(markerClicked)
        {
            if(polygon != null)
            {
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            polygonOptions.strokeWidth(5);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(0x884d4d4d);

            polygon = myMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
            marker.remove();

        }
        else    
        {
            if(polygon != null)
            {
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
            markerClicked = true;
            marker.remove();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Long Press to select locations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

using this fragment

```
fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Also read the official Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon).

Comment: is there any way to add a background image to a area .. as an example if we  separate Australia is there any way to add a background image  rather than adding a polygon or a color

Comment: ok what you want is to use is GroundOverlay . Check my new ans.

Answer (score 1):

Replace codes in getInfoContents with getInfoWindow. The difference between them is getInfoContents wraps your View in ViewGroup with default background.
[try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519377/5082129)

Comment: can you add an example nuke ;)