# Put a Bitmap on a picture template and add as a Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

Right now, I'm getting a picture from a URL and storing it as a bitmap. What I want to do, is take the picture and resize it then place it on top of a 'template' picture (something like below, to be a resource file in the drawable folder) and place it on a GoogleMap as a marker.

I read you can create a canvas out of a picture, I'm just not sure how I can place another picture on top of another.

[image: template picture]

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586876/how-can-i-create-a-speech-bubble-border-for-a-google-marker-custom-icon-using-pi

Comment: Cheers @DanielNugent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Bitmap makeStackedBitmap(final Bitmap background, final Bitmap foreground)
{
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), background.getConfig());   //Initialize the result image
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);   //Create a canvas so we can draw onto the result image
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);   //Draw the background
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, null);   //Draw the foreground. Change (0, 0) if you want.
    return result;   //Returns single image with the background and foreground
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the bitmap image does not need to resize to add on marker. Marker has a default size on Maps. Use the saved bitmap image as marker image.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(your_latLng)
            .draggable(your_choice)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_saved_image/bitmap)));
```

Comment: "then place it on top of a 'template' picture (something like below, to be a resource file in the drawable folder)"