# How to set image in google marker with a border in Android?

Tags: firebase, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers, geofire

I have profile photo of users stored in Firebase and I want to know how I can create a marker with the user's profile photo with an orange border.

I tried some code from the internet and it works but the measurements seem to be wrong and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The code I used:

```
fun setMarkerPhoto(user:User, location: Location){
    var bitmapFinal : Bitmap?

    if(hasProfilePhoto){
        /*val options = RequestOptions()
        options.centerCrop()*/
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                /*.apply(options)*/
                .centerCrop()
                .load(user.image)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        bitmapFinal = createUserBitmapFinal(resource)



                        markerOptions
                                .position(LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude))
                                .title("Current Location")
                                .snippet(address)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapFinal))


                        mCurrentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })
    }else{
        markerOptions
                .position(LatLng(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation!!.longitude))
                .title("Current Location")
                .snippet(address)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))



        mCurrentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }
}

 private fun createUserBitmapFinal(bitmapInicial: Bitmap?): Bitmap? {
    var result: Bitmap? = null
    try {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(150,150, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) //change the size of the placeholder
        result.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val drawable: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pickup)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 150,150) //change the size of the placeholder, but you need to maintain the same proportion of the first line
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        val roundPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        val bitmapRect = RectF()
        canvas.save()

        if (bitmapInicial != null) {
            val shader =
                    BitmapShader(bitmapInicial, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
            val matrix = Matrix()
            val scale: Float = 200 / bitmapInicial.width.toFloat()  //reduce or augment here change the size of the original bitmap inside the placehoder.
            // But you need to adjust the line bitmapRect with the same proportion
            matrix.postTranslate(5f, 5f)
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale)
            roundPaint.shader = shader
            shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix)
            bitmapRect[10f, 10f, 104f+10f]=104f+10f //change here too to change the size
            canvas.drawRoundRect(bitmapRect, 56f, 56f, roundPaint)
        }
```

I didn't really understand how to perfectly fit the bitmap image inside the placeholder. My marker looked like this:

[image: marker]

also the image wasn't being center cropped even though I mentioned that it should be in the code, where it says **Glide.centerCrop()**

Also, I'm using GeoFire to display markers of users in a specified radius of the user and for now I can display a simple marker but I want the marker to have that user's profile photo too! How can I do it?

GeoFire Code:

```
val geoQuery: GeoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude), 0.5)
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
        override fun onKeyEntered(key: String, location: GeoLocation) {
            println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude))
            Log.i("key entered","User found around you")
            val aroundYou = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)

            
            if (markerList != null) {
                for (marker in markerList) {
                    marker.remove()
                }
            }

            otherMarkerOptions
                    .position(aroundYou)
                    .title("Current Location")
                    //.snippet(address)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)) //This is a simple marker but i want it to have the user's profile photo 

            
            markerList.add(googleMap.addMarker(otherMarkerOptions))

            //}
        }
```

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

In the line: `val drawable: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pickup)`

It's this png:

[image: placeholder]

I want to insert the profile photo of the user on that drawable file and if the user doesn't have a profile photo then only the drawable photo will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You get the code to transform the bitmap from my code in another question in StrackOverflow. As I mentioned there, I can´t teste the code because i´m only working with flutter right now.

But looking ate your code I might try this:

Add this function:

```
fun dp(value: Float): Int {
    return if (value == 0f) {
        0
    } else Math.ceil(resources.displayMetrics.density * value.toDouble()).toInt()
}
```

in your lines:

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(150,150, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 150,150);
```

change to:

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(dp(62f), dp(76f), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, dp(150f), dp(150f)) ;
```

let me know the results.

Comment: I did what you mentioned and the placeholder became way more larger. Here's how it looked after I tried what you said https://ibb.co/9sQLBPF , Also I edited the question can you please check it? Thank you