# iOS Google Map Marker with a photo inside round bubble with arrow

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I need a custom marker in google maps,I found a link which is in Android [How to make a Google Map Marker with a photo inside round speech-bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143203/how-to-make-a-google-map-marker-with-a-photo-inside-round-speech-bubble).
Can anyone give me idea how I can do in objective - c.

Comment: see this for help pa : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210145/google-maps-ios-sdk-custom-icons-to-be-used-as-markers

Answer (score 1):

Use `iconView` property of `GMSMarker` to render the customized view as marker.

**Code:**

```
UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Picture"];
picture = [picture imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImageView *pictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: picture];
pictureView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.iconView = pictureView;
marker.tracksViewChanges = YES;
marker.map = self.mapView;
```

For more, please visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
london.title = @"London";
london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house"];
london.map = mapView;
```