# Custom Marker on Google Map Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a used custom marker in my Google Map App with help of Bitmap and canvas . The image on marker is coming fine when i run it on device with android version 5.1 or any other except 4.4.

I am sure its not a version issue . but i am confused and unable to figure out where i done mistake . Please help me to find it .

**Custom marker (Bitmap) Code:**

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128, conf);
            Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);


    canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.map_markers_green), 0, 0, color);

                canvas1.drawText(String.valueOf(a).toUpperCase(), 56, 53, color);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                                // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

**Marker image which is working fine on device:**

[image]

**Same marker image which is coming cut on different device :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 50, conf); 
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawText("TEXT", 0, 50, paint); // paint defines the textcolor, stroke width, size
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(clickedPosition)
                            //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker2))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 1)
                                );
```

Comment: No , problem still same with this code as well . Not working for me .

Comment: try this Link solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-android-map-api-v2-custom-marker-with-imageview)

Comment: i have done same in my code that's why its working fine on same devices .  But in some devices , the marker get cut off for some reason .

Comment: you put all size image in drawable.?

Comment: yes , i did . I have used hit and trial method with almost every size image but problem remain same . My custom marker getting cut off .

Comment: There is also a thing , it might get solved by increasing width and height in Bitmap . But doing these changes will create problem on devices which working fine with this  code .

Comment: try on draw text method put 0 instead of 56 and on create bitmap method second parameter put 32 instead of 128

Comment: Vishal , but changing bitmap and draw method will create issue on devices on which this code working fine . Thats why i am reluctant to change it . I want to modify it in a way that work fine on every device .

Comment: yes . I have taken help from your code and applied to mine . And it resolved .