# Custom google maps marker with user image inside the pin

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to display users on a map, i have already implemented the map in the app, but now i am trying to make custom markers that display a users' photo inside the pin something like this: [Custom markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT0tb.png) , how can i accomplish this?

To clarify, what i am trying to do is display a bitmap inside a marker icon bitmap

Comment: This link might help you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2

Answer (score 2):

You can define an icon to show instead of the default marker image. Defining an icon involves setting a number of properties that determine the visual behavior of the marker. Below code should do the trick.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
  });

  var image = 'filePath' + 'usersPhoto.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
```

Check the Google Maps API for details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple#try-it-yourself

Comment: I am not using javascript, i know how to change the icon, i need a way to put the user image inside a pin,like in the example i mentioned. thanks anyways