# Android: Convert Bitmap image to Image giving a look like Marker

Tags: android, canvas, google-maps-markers, android-canvas, image-editing

I have an Image stored in Bitmap variable **image** which is in the form of a square-shaped image. Please Help me Out to make the image as shown in line [Link For Image of Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJqLH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom-shaped bitmap marker with Android map API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2)

Comment: Didn't found to create canvas bitmap similar to my image. Plz, help me out if you can @humazed