# How to put a picture in a infowindow in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

How do I put a picture inside a infowindow in my android application running with google maps?

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(MELBOURNE)
            .title("Melbourne")
            .snippet("Population: 4'137'400"));
```

That's how I add some Text but I don't know how to put an image in it. And furthermore, where do I have to save it?

So far, my app works but only without an image.

/Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2

Comment: nah, I want to put the image in the infowindow, not as a marker

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate layout and then you can put image in infoWindow.

Refer this code:

```
  googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
          @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            View v = getApplicationContext().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_map_screen_new, null);

             return v;
           };
           @Override
         public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
             return null;
         }
    });
```

Comment: and where can I save my images? Please give me a filepath

Comment: Images are dynamic or static . If images are static then you can place it in drawable and if images are dynamic then you can get it from server , just set the bitmap to image view.

Comment: If my answer is correct then please mark as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but the code doesn't work properly. Following Error appears: 'error: cannot find symbol variable conntext, execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. The 'context.get...' is marked red

Comment: Ohoo , I am just guide about code. So you have to code for some variables like context = this  and other strings. So You can use your layout and in context you can use getApplicationContext() as well.

Comment: Okay, I'll try in some minutes