# android - how to add custom label on the google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I want to stick labels on the screen ( not marker ) like this :

[image]

how can I add this blue text to the map **beside** marker?

Comment: You need it at one place or on many places??

Comment: @CodeLღver : many place

Comment: look at this article : https://support.google.com/business/answer/6056435?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a custom `Bitmap` with the blue text and icon and set it using the `icon` method of `Marker` object.

```
// add marker to Map
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(USER_POSITION)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(YOUR_CUSTOM_BITMAP))
    // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
    .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

Detailed example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2)