# Is there any way to remove icons and labels from Google Maps and add custom icons and labels for places?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a college based Android application. I need to create a custom map for college campus and want to replace google's icons and labels with my own. 
Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2

Comment: thanks, @JaspreetKaur. But I don't think that solution removes google's icons and labels. We can add our icons and labels but, I want to show only my labels, not Google's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide default icons and labels for POIs you have to create a custom styled map. For example the following style is hiding default POIs

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You should create a resource file that contains your custom style (e.g. `/res/raw/style_json.json`) and apply it when your map is loading

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }
    // Position the map's camera near Sydney, Australia.
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-34, 151)));
}
```

For detailed information please follow the tutorial:

[Adding a Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling)

To create your own markers you should follow

[Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

I hope this helps!